# Help with my LED multiple bulb circuit (beginner)

Tags: led, circuit-analysis

I will start by saying I've been researching how to create circuits for a few days coming from knowing nothing, so if anything I say sounds dead wrong I apologize.

What I'm essentially trying to do is create a small modular lamp containing 1 LED bulb per "block", and each block can be plugged into the previous adding more "nodes" to the lamp. I've created the basic circuit diagram and found the parts I would like to try to use and I was hoping you could tell me if it could work or if I'm way off base.

For the power supply I would use a [12 volt 2.0 amp wall wart](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KZ2ZQE8). This would plug into the bottom of the first block via this [2.1mm barrel jack](https://www.adafruit.com/products/610). From there onward each block will have the same barrel jack on the *top* of the block that can be plugged into via this [2.1mm male adapter](https://www.adafruit.com/products/369) at the bottom of each subsequent block. Inside each block I will be powering a single [12v 2watt LED](https://www.walmart.com/ip/3-Pack-2W-G4-LED-Light-Bulb-20W-Halogen-Bulb-Equivalent-AC-DC-12V-Soft-White-2700K-360-Omnidirectional-LED-Bi-pin-Base-G4-Bulb-Cabinet-Pendant-Auto-R/124040168).

I only want to power 5 of these blocks. Having my math checked at another forum showed that the 5 block at 2W each = 10W divided by 12volt = 0.83amps so even with some built in margin of error I'm under the 2amp from my power supply.

However, I read the tech specs of the barrel jack I linked and it says it has a rated current of .5amp. Is that per block (2W/12v=.16a) or is that for the whole setup meaning it can't handle my .83a?

Also I was wondering if there was any way to go about limiting it to just the 5 blocks? Assuming someone else got a hold of these plus some spares and plugged in say 8 blocks it would overheat and be dangerous correct? Is there a way to build in a shutoff past 5 mechanism?

I don't know how to use those fancy mockups I keep seeing so here is a MS paint rendering of what I'm talking about:
[image]

*(the arrows are to indicate the direction the blocks are being plugged into each other)*

Would this work?

Comment: The 0.5A limit on each connector is due to a pre-defined temperature rise of contact area with margin for aging.  You can use larger connectors and include a polyfuse in each module for short circuit protection and gross overcurrent or rely  on a label warning.

Comment: You can get the same size barrel connectors with a higher current rating if you search a bit.